# On the continuity of a step function

Tags: continuity, step-function

Let $g : \Bbb R \to [0, 1]$ be a non-decreasing and right-continuous step function such that

$$ g (x) := \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \le 0\\ 1 & \text{if } x \ge 1\end{cases}$$

Let us define $g^{−1}$ as follows,

$$ g^{-1}(y) := \inf \left\{ x \ge 0 \mid g(x) \ge y \right\} $$

The answer provided to me is that  $g^{-1}$  is left-continuous but not right-continuous.

I think that the question is wrong because the function is not defined for values in the interval of $(0,1)$. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: you are supposed to show the statement for an arbitrary function $g$ with the stated properties. And this $g$ is only _restricted_ to $0$ for $x\le0$ and restricted to $1$ for $x\ge 1$ but can take arbitrary values in between. It isn't a definition

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo for example $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x> 0 \\ 0 & x\le0\end{cases}$ It is continuous everywhere but in $0$, and it is left-continuous in zero, because $\lim_{t\uparrow 0} f(t) = 0 = f(0)$. But not right-continuous

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts why? The second condition is $x \geq 1$, not $x \geq 0$.

Comment: oooops, my bad.